# Adding Ext JS Loading clock icon while form is being loaded

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to add a `clock` like animated clock to display while a particular form is populated with data. Can someone tell me how this is done.

I show a small window with the image of the clock when the form has started to load, and then close that window once the data is loaded. I don't think this is the correct approach, so can someone tell me how can i get this done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setLoading method of the form. Look at:

```
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setLoading
```